# Django Australian local flavor form validation

Tags: django, localization, django-forms, django-views

I'm having trouble getting django's `django.contrib.localflavor.au.forms` to validate my form input.

I have tried several ways to use the form widgets and have had no success. The form will display but not validate. Though it is very possible I'm doing something incorrect.
My form code is as follows using a custom widget. Django version is 1.2.3

```
from django.contrib.localflavor.au.forms import AUStateSelect, AUPostCodeField, AUPhoneNumberField
...    
class ContactForm(ModelForm):
       class Meta:
          model = Contact
          fields = ('name', 'state')
          widgets = { 'state': AUStateSelect() }
          exclude = ['created']
```

I have also tried using a custom form field this way.

```
from django.contrib.localflavor.au.forms import AUStateSelect, AUPostCodeField, AUPhoneNumberField
...
    class ContactForm(ModelForm):
       class Meta:
          model = Contact
          exclude = ['created']
       state = AUStateSelect()
```

Either version does not display the select widget. No validation happens with `AUPostCodeField` or `AUPhoneNumberField` widgets either.

This is the code I use to add data to the database and check for valid input.

```
def addContact(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      contactForm = ContactForm(request.POST)

      if contactForm.is_valid():
         contactForm.save()

   return HttpResponseRedirect('scrapyard.views.main')
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could test if it's a bug in your code or in the AU localflavor by temporarily swapping out for the US localflavor.

Comment: Which django version are you using? The `widgets` attribute of the `Meta` class needs django >= 1.2!

Comment: While `AUStateSelect` is a widget that doesn't do any validation the two other classes you mention are FIELD classes!

Comment: @Seth The USStateSelect works as a custom widget. But not AUStateSelect. Thanks!

Comment: @lazerscience Django version is 1.2.3 and I'm aware that AUPostCodeField and AUPhoneNumberField are fields. I will edit the post to correct this.

Comment: Well I working after I included all the form field values. I restarted apache and there it was. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well I got it working(AUStateSelect) after I included all the form field values in the . Then I added the AUPostCodeField and now the form does not render....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class ContactForm(ModelForm):
       class Meta:
          model = Contact
          exclude = ['created']
          widgets = { 'state': AUStateSelect() }
```

Whether the order was involved or not this segment worked like a charm.
Obviously an over site on my behalf.

Thanks everybody for your help.